# How to create extension method on enumeration (c#)

Tags: c#, enums, extension-methods

I want to create an extension method that will return an enum value by its key. 
The usage will be

```
LifeCycle.GetLifeCycle(1)
```

or 
    LifeCycle.GetLifeCycleByValue("")

Here is what I thought of - Let's say I have the following enum :

```
public enum LifeCycle
{
    Pending = 0,
    Approved = 1,
    Rejected = 2,
}
```

And I wrote the following extension for the getByint case

```
public static class EnumerationExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<int, LifeCycle> _lifeCycleMap = Enum.GetValues(typeof(LifeCycle)).Cast<int>().ToDictionary(Key => Key, value => ((LifeCycle)value));

    public static LifeCycle GetLifeCycle(this LifeCycle lifeCycle, int lifeCycleKey)
    {
        return _lifeCycleMap[lifeCycleKey];
    }
}
```

So far

```
 LifeCycle.GetLifeCycle(1)
```

doenst compile.

Is that even possible ?

Comment: Actually, you can write *no code at all* and just use `var foo = (LifeCycle)1;`. Isn't that satisfactory?

Comment: @Jon The difference there is that if you give it an invalid value it will work just fine, instead of throwing an exception.  That may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @Servy: Sure. But you *can* write an `EnsureValid(this LifeCycle lc)` method that throws if `Enum.HasValue(lc.GetType(), lc)` is `false`, if that's the problem.

Comment: This is a general case. I want to be able to do it with the value too. I will update the question soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LifeCycle` is the type not an instance of that enum.

So this would compile:

```
LifeCycle.Pending.GetLifeCycle(1);
```

But this extension is pointless anyway since you could get an enum by it's `int` value directly:

```
LifeCycle approved = (LifeCycle) 1;
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as a static extension method, which is what you're trying to do.  You can only create extension methods that act in instances of a type, not the type itself.

Answer (score 1):

You just need cast like this:

```
var lifeCycle = (LifeCycle)1;
```

Here go some example:

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var lifeCycle = (LifeCycle)1;
            Console.WriteLine(lifeCycle);
            //Output: Approved
        }
    }

    public enum LifeCycle
    {
        Pending = 0,
        Approved = 1,
        Rejected = 2,
    }
}
```